# how do i solve the flutter problem "Error.throwWithStackTrace"

Tags: flutter

`Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
: Error: Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
Error.throwWithStackTrace(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.
Never convertPlatformException(Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
^
Failed to compile application.
Exited (sigterm)

what is the solution`

Comment: add your code !!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `Error.throwWithStackTrace` was added in Dart 2.16.  What is the output from `flutter doctor`?  Does your `pubspec.yaml` file require Dart 2.16 or greater?